# grahviz neato "failure to create cairo surface"

Tags: graphviz

I am receiving this error:

```
>neato house.dot -Tgif -o house2.gif -Tdot -o x.dot
neato: failure to create cairo surface: out of memory

>neato -V
neato - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20110507.0327)
```

I have lots of memory - about 5Gigs free

Here is house.dot

```
graph g {
node [shape=box]
north [ pos = "286.0,370.0!" ];
Vestibulo -- Escalera
Sala -- Vestibulo
Comedor -- Sala
CocServ -- Comedor
DormP -- BanoP
DormH -- Bano
Sala -- Bano
Sala -- DormP
CocServ -- north
}
```

If I unpin the 'north' node then neato completes without error - but North is not located where I want it.

I have upgraded to graphviz version 2.30.1 - still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
dot -Tsvg 99winsert.gv -v > out.svg
```

you can try **transform to svg** not png, then you can browse it from Chrome or transform svg to png. it won`t failed since too much memory allocated.

> failure to create cairo surface: out of memory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The work around is to use smaller values for the pinned locations.

Like this:

```
graph g {
node [shape=box]
north [ pos = "1.0,10.0!" ];
south [ pos = "1.0,-10.0!" ];
east [ pos = "-10.0,0.0!" ];
west [ pos = "10.0,0.0!" ];
Vestibulo -- Escalera
Sala -- Vestibulo
Comedor -- Sala
CocServ -- Comedor
DormP -- BanoP
DormH -- Bano
Sala -- Bano
Sala -- DormP
CocServ -- north
}
```

Which produces this

[image]